# separate callback function java script

Tags: javascript

I'm using from kcfinder in my web page it is ok but only one problem;
i need to separate callback function and use it further ...but i can't

```
function openKCFinder(div) {
window.KCFinder = {
    callBack: function(url) {
///all action 
}
```

//i need something similar this 
///it is not work;

```
function set_pic(url,div){
    ///all action
}
function openKCFinder(div) {
  window.KCFinder = {
    callBack: set_pic(url,div) ;
 }
```

thanks for help me.

and excuse me for poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code runs `set_pic(url,div)` right away; its return value is assigned to `callback`.  Try: `callback: function(){ set_pic(url, div); }`

Answer (score 1):

Just make another function:

```
   callback: function(url) { set_pic(url, div); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this code hopefully solved this issue**

```
function set_pic(url, div,callBack) {

    callBack(div)
}

function openKCFinder(div) {
    window.KCFinder = {
        callBack: set_pic(url, div)
    }
}

set_pic('passing url','passing div', openKCFinder(div))
```